# Mock stateless Servicefabric class methods/variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am writing an end-to-end test for the RestAPI.  The restAPI is using some fields from a service fabric class (MyClass). I want to mock those values but not able to achieve. The servicefabric class looks like following:

```
public class MyClass : StatelessService
{
   private static MyClass singleton;
   private string a;

   public MyClass(StatelessServiceContext context) : base(context) {
      singleton = this;
      this.a = "A";
   }

   public static MyClass Singleton => singleton;

   public string GetA => a;
}
```

The controller is using the above class as following.

```
public class MyContrller: ControllerBase
{
   private MyClass myclass;

   public MyContrller()
   {
      this.myclass = MyClass.Singleton;
   }

   [HttpGet]
   [Route("someRoute")]
   public Result GetData()
   {
     //some logic
     var a = myclass.GetA;
     //some logic
   }
}
```

Now the unittest for the RestAPI:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{
   private Mock<MyClass> mockMyClass = new Mock<MyClass>();

   [TestMethod]
   [DataSource(Excel file having multiple values for a and expected result)]
   public void TestGetData()
   {
     string x = this.TestContext.DataRow["a"].ToString();
     Result expectedResult = this.TestContext.DataRow["result"];

     this.mockMyClass.Setup(m => m.GetA).Returns(x);

     var result = client.callGetData();

     CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
   }
}
```

Even though the unittest is sending "X", "Y".. values for the myclass.GetA. But it still not changing from the value getting set in the Myclass constructor which is "A".

I did figure out that I have to mock Myclass.Singleton also. So, I added the below code in my test method. But it's not correct and throwing "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". How can we mock those values in the RestAPI?

```
this.mockMyClass.CallBase = true;
this.mockSigningAPI.Setup(m => SigningRestAPI.Singleton).Returns(this.mockSigningAPI.Object);
```

Comment: Is `client` constructed to take your mock class?

Comment: @itsdaniel0 Yes, I have constructed the client to call the RestAPI.

Comment: Hi, I think your mocked instance of MyClass is not being injected into your controller. One of your controllers is using a singleton instance of MyClass. Because it is a static variable you cannot modify it. Please tell me if you need to explain.

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT Yes, that's what happening. Controller is using singleton instance of MyClass. I don't think so there is any way to mock this for the end-to-end test.

Comment: @AartiJangid Hello, if your controller is using a static instance of MyClass, it can be difficult to mock it in an end-to-end test. It's worth noting that relying heavily on static variables can make your code difficult to test and maintain in the long run.

Comment: If your issue has new progress, you can share it so that you can help more people

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you're mocking a class, but the singleton is assigned in the constructor

You can make the property settable, then override it with your mock

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private static MyClass singleton;

    public MyClass()
    {
        Singleton = this;
    }

    public static MyClass Singleton
    {
        get
        {
            return singleton;
        }
        set
        {
            singleton = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in you're unit test, assign the singleton to the mock

```cs
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{   
    private Mock<MyClass> myMockClass = new Mock<MyClass>();

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialise()
    {
        MyClass.Singleton = mock;
    }
}
```

You can make the setter internal, and use `InternalsVisibleTo` allowing only your test project to set it.
When you Mock a class, it doesn't call any of the base methods. Setting `CallBase = true` will call the base for methods/properties, but not the constructor.

Comment: A property cannot be created before constructor. Hence, I have to create getter method below the constructor. This getter method required to be static otherwise whoever is calling, will need to create context. I cannot control the creation of Singleton from Test class.

Comment: @AartiJangid I haven't seen that error before, but you can move the property below the constructor. The importance in the answer is the setter on the property

Comment: @itsdaniel10 When I am using property before constructor then it's throwing SA1201. So, I created a setter method after constructor to update the MyClass.Singleton.. It's saying, "Can not be assigned it's read only."

Comment: Then I tried creating the setter for the var A in MyClass and thought of directly updating this value from unit test without mocking. But when I am calling MyClass.Singleton.SetA(var a) - It's throwing "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Basically MyClass.Singleton is null even though the service is created in service fabric. The unittest class is in different folder but part of same solution.

Comment: Like I've put in my answer, you need to assign the **singleton** value, then it won't be null

Comment: Thanks for your input. What you told works for unit test. I am writing end-to-end test which is a different service.

Answer (score 1):

I created two APIs in the controller class to update and reset the variables of singleton class. From End to End test, I first called the update method with the values and once test is done. I called the reset method which will set the default value again for these variables.

I have also put some validation for these APIs so that call from E2E tests only will  be able to update these values.